# Cannot call method 'css' of null jQuery.nivoSlider.afterLoad - Joomla 2.5 - Vinaora NivoSlider

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5, nivo-slider

My Vinaora Nivo Slider Joomla 2.5 module returns me this error under Chrome inspector:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'css' of null pagehtml:401
>   jQuery.nivoSlider.afterLoad pagehtml:401 t
>   jquery.nivo.slider.min.js:10 (anonymous function)
>   jquery.nivo.slider.min.js:10 x.extend.each jquery.min.js:4 x.fn.x.each
>   jquery.min.js:4 e.fn.nivoSlider jquery.nivo.slider.min.js:10
>   (anonymous function) pagehtml:379 x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
>   v.handle

It seems that afterLoad function is not called properly and maybe it needs NoConflict method.
I'm trying to solve this issue by editing the file /modules/mod_vt_nivo_slider/tmpl/_script.php without success...

this is the original version of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#vt_nivo_slider<?php echo $module_id; ?>').nivoSlider({
        effect: '<?php echo $effect; ?>', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: <?php echo $slices; ?>, // For slice animations
        boxCols: <?php echo $boxCols; ?>, // For box animations
        boxRows: <?php echo $boxRows; ?>, // For box animations
        animSpeed: <?php echo $animSpeed; ?>, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: <?php echo $pauseTime; ?>, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: <?php echo $startSlide; ?>, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: <?php echo $directionNav; ?>, // Next & Prev navigation
        controlNav: <?php echo $controlNav; ?>, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: <?php echo $controlNavThumbs; ?>, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        pauseOnHover: <?php echo $pauseOnHover; ?>, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: <?php echo $manualAdvance; ?>, // Force manual transitions
        prevText: '<?php echo $prevText; ?>', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: '<?php echo $nextText; ?>', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: <?php echo $randomStart; ?>, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){
            var $slider = $('.nivoSlider img');
    $slider.css('opacity',0);
    $('.nivoSlider').fadeOut(500, function(){
       $slider.animate({'opacity':1}, 500);
    });
} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in Joomla. The `$` symbole is actually mootool since it is linked after jQuery.

There is multiple solutions to solve that but im giving you my favorite one. Wrap you entire code in a closure :

```
(function($){
    //Your code here, then you will be able to use $ as jQuery, not mootool
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: With copy and paste your code, it returns me this error right after "var $slider = $('.nivoSlider img');" : Uncaght TypeError:object is not a function